# cant call publishProgress from inside a onDataChange()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-asynctask

```
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference(address[0]+"/"+address[1]);
                myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
             // This method is called once with the initial value and again
             // whenever data at this location is updated.
             String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                        publishProgress(getping(value));
       }
```

publishProgress always gets skipped.

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot. and tell us what is the value of `address[0]+"/"+address[1]`?

Comment: what does getping() ?

Comment: @AlexMamo its a string value that i use from Async task params.

Comment: @GastónSaillén returns a Long